# Do buffered channels maintain order?

Tags: go, channel

In Go, do buffered channels have any order guarantee?

For example:
you have two goroutines A & B that share a channel. A pushes data onto the channel while B reads from it. Are you guranted that B will read data In the same order that A put it into the channel?

I understand that if there are multiple producers or consumers the order may be non-deterministic, but I'm specifically asking about having just 1 producer and 1 consumer.

Comment: [Send statements: "... Communication blocks until the send can proceed..."](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> "Are you guaranteed that B will read data In the same order that A put it into the channel?"

Yes. The order of data is guaranteed.
But the *delivery* is guaranteed only for unbuffered channels, *not* buffered.
(see second section of this answer)

---

You can see the idea of channels illustrated in "[The Nature Of Channels In Go](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/02/the-nature-of-channels-in-go.html)" from **[William Kennedy](https://twitter.com/goinggodotnet)** (Feb. 2014): it shows how the order or read/write is respected.
See also [Channels](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels):

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive.
>
> - If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value.
> - If the channel has a buffer, the sender blocks only until the value has been copied to the buffer; if the buffer is full, this means waiting until some receiver has retrieved a value.

### Unbuffered Channels

[image: https://www.ardanlabs.com/images/goinggo/Screen+Shot+2014-02-16+at+10.10.54+AM.png]

### Buffered Channel

[image: https://www.ardanlabs.com/images/goinggo/Screen+Shot+2014-02-17+at+8.38.15+AM.png]

<sup>Image source: [Ardan labs - William Kennedy](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/02/the-nature-of-channels-in-go.html)</sup>

---

The same William Kennedy details the **Guarantee Of Delivery** aspect in "**[The Behavior Of Channels](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/10/the-behavior-of-channels.html)**" (Oct 2017)

> Do I need a guarantee that the signal sent by a particular goroutine has been received?

[image: https://www.ardanlabs.com/images/goinggo/86_signaling_with_data.png]

<sup>Image source: Again, [Ardan labs - William Kennedy](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/10/the-behavior-of-channels.html)</sup>

> The three channel options are Unbuffered, Buffered >1 or Buffered =1.
>
> - **Guarantee**
>
>   - An **Unbuffered** channel gives you a **Guarantee** that a signal being sent has been received.
>
>     - Because the **Receive of the signal Happens Before the Send** of the signal completes.
> - **No Guarantee**
>
>   - A **Buffered** channel of **size >1** gives you **No Guarantee** that a signal being sent has been received.
>
>     - Because the **Send** of the signal **Happens Before the Receive** of the signal completes.
> - **Delayed Guarantee**
>
>   - A **Buffered** channel of **size =1** gives you a **Delayed Guarantee**. It can guarantee that the previous signal that was sent has been received.
>
>     - Because the **Receive of the First Signal, Happens Before the Send of the Second Signal** completes.

Comment: great use of image to explain the concept!!

Comment: A Yes or No for "Are you guranted that B will read data In the same order that A put it into the channel?" for this part would he helpful. Great answer though.

Comment: @sofs1 Good point. I have added a first section to the answer in order to make that more explicit. But I also point out that the *delivery* itself is not always guaranteed.

Comment: @VonC You are awesome.