# understand the code - Go concurrency pattern: Daisy Chain

Tags: concurrency, go

I was studying Go concurrency pattern.

One pattern I am not sure is： Daisy Chain   https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#39

It's very hard for me to understand the control flow of the code.

Can someone explain to me ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func f(left, right chan int) {
    left <- 1 + <-right
}

func main() {
    const n = 10000

    leftmost := make(chan int)
    right := leftmost               //point B: what does these do ?
    left := leftmost

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        right = make(chan int)
        go f(left, right)
        left = right                //point A
    }
    go func(c chan int) { c <- 1 }(right)  
    fmt.Println(<-leftmost)
}
```

**Conclusion**:

1. the flow of channel going from right to left. It is good practice to write 
   `func f(left chan<- int, right <-chan int)` rather than original function signature as above.
2. 'chain reaction' does not start until c <- 1, when signal 1 is sent to right most channel,
   reaction goes all the way to left most end. Print out 10001.

The reason is go channel block 'read' until received channel receive signal.

3. @Rick-777 shows how to use array like structure for easy understanding.
   Since each go coroutine is just around 6k big. It's not a bad idea to make 10k channel.
4. I clean up some code around Point B, for channel initialization.
   Here is the source code:
   http://play.golang.org/p/1kFYPypr0l

Comment: Your version looks good. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found dry-run this program could be really helpful to understand it.

At first, after executing

```golang
leftmost := make(chan int)
right := leftmost
left := leftmost
```

`leftmost`, `left`, and `right` are all referring to the same `chan int`

```
[chan int]
     |                 
left, leftmost, right
```

Let's run some iterations for the for-loop.

`i = 0`

When we just enter the for loop,

```
[chan int]
     |                 
left, leftmost, right
```

after executing `right = make(chan int)` and `go f(left, right)`.

```
[chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int]
     |                 |
left, leftmost        right
```

after executing `left = right`

```
[chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int]
     |                 |
  leftmost        left, right
```

`i = 1`

When we just enter the for loop,

```
[chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int]
     |                 |
  leftmost        left, right
```

after executing `right = make(chan int)` and `go f(left, right)`.

```
[chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int]
     |                 |                   |
  leftmost            left               right
```

after executing `left = right`

```
[chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int]
     |                                     |
  leftmost                            left, right
```

I feel like two loops are enough to see the pattern:

- Every loop we create a new `chan int` and append it at the end of the "linked list of `chan int`".
- So after `n = 100000` loops, we created `100000` new `chan int`, and the number of `chan int` in the "linked list of `chan int` will be `100001`.
- `100001` `chan int` means `100000` gaps between each pair of adjacent `chan int`, and each gap means one `+1`.

Before the for loop, because all `chan int` are acting as receivers and there is no pass-in value, so all `chan int` will just wait.

After the for loop, we execute `go func(c chan int) { c <- 1 }(right)`, then the `1` is passed into the "linked list of `chan int`" and perform `+1` on the value for `100000` times, so the final result to the `leftmost` will be `100001`.

Things will be like when we pass `1` into the "linked list of `chan int`":

```
[chan int] <-(+1)- [chan int] <-(+1)- ...... <-(+1)- [chan int] <- 1
     |                                                   |
  leftmost                                           left, right
```

I created a leetcode playground holding all the code. You could try it [here](https://leetcode.com/playground/gAa59fh3) (https://leetcode.com/playground/gAa59fh3).

Answer (score 7):

VonC has already given a direct answer. Here are some further remarks.

A slightly tidied-up version is in [the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/sLRTI6p3ie), the difference being that the channels passed as parameters have their direction specified explicitly, ie. `<-chan` and `chan<-`. It's good practice to do this because the compiler can catch more mistakes for you.

**An alternative and equivalent program** that has a daisy-chain of `n` goroutines can be written using an array of channels instead. This allocates the same total number of channels using fewer lines of code. See [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/57kZiB8YVk):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func f(left chan<- int, right <-chan int) {
    left <- 1 + <-right
}

func main() {
    const n = 10000

    // first we construct an array of n+1 channels each being a 'chan int'
    var channels [n+1]chan int
    for i := range channels {
        channels[i] = make(chan int)
    }

    // now we wire n goroutines in a chain
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go f(channels[i], channels[i+1])
    }

    // insert a value into the right-hand end
    go func(c chan<- int) { c <- 1 }(channels[n])

    // pick up the value emerging from the left-hand end
    fmt.Println(<-channels[0])
}
```

I hope you can see now how the original program is equivalent to this program. There is one minor difference: the original program does not create any channel array, so uses just a little less memory.

Comment: I like the array approach. +1

Comment: Yes, it's easy to understand -- but it's good to know that the array isn't strictly necessary (as per the original program) so you can save some memory. *Is low memory more important that code clarity?* (always a useful question - there is no always-right answer)

Answer (score 5):

It illustrates you can generate a large number of goroutines.

Here, each `go f(left, right)` blocks: `left <- 1 + <-right` blocks because it waits for `right` to get a value. See "[do golang channels maintain order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795236/6309)".
All channels created here are unbuffered channels.

All 10000 goroutines are created.

Point B: `right` and `left` are declared, using the [short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

- `right` is initialized to leftmost, but it doesn't matter, because it will be reassigned to a new channel in the `for` loop (`right = make(chan int)`).
  Another way to declare right would have been:

  ```
  var right chan int
  ```
- `left` is initialized with `leftmost`, the very first channel created.

Point A: But once that channel start waiting (`left <- 1 + <-right`), the `for` loop set left to `right`, and created a new `right`: that is how the daisy chain is build

```
 left <- (new) right (now left) <- (new) right (now left) <- ...
```

Then, one value is sent to the last `right` channel created: {`c <- 1 }(right)`

And you wait for the first `leftmost` channel created to receive its value (incremented 10000 time).

Since receivers always block until there is data to receive, the `main()` function itself doesn't exit before `leftmost` finally receive its value.
If `main()` exited too soon, the daisy chain wouldn't have time to complete.

Comment: I am not sure about the code in Point A and Point B. These syntax really confuse me. Would you mind explain a little bit ?