# Returning Channels Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying with Go channels and confused with below function example from go blog:

```
func gen(nums []int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    fmt.Println("return statement is called ")
    return out
}
```

Main :

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    c = gen([]int{2, 3, 4, 5})

    // Consume the output.
    // Print 2,3,4,5
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
    fmt.Println(<-c)
}
```

Complete Code: http://play.golang.org/p/Qh30wzo4m0

My Doubts:

1. My understanding was, once `return` is called the function will be terminated and the channel inside that function has no more life.
2. The `return` statement is called only once. But the content of the `out` channel is read many times. In this case what is the actual flow of execution?

(I'm new to concurrent programming.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
out := make(chan int)
```

This is not a buffered channel, which means the `out <- n` will **block** until someone somewhere reads that channel (the `fmt.Println(<-c)` calls)
(See also "[do golang channels maintain order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795236/6309)")

So the return at the end of the `gen()` function doesn't mean the literal `go func()` is terminated (since it is still waiting for readers to consume the content of the `out` channel).

> But `main` function getting `out` channel as return from `gen()` function.
> How it is possible to get it after `gen()` is terminated?

The fact that `gen()` terminates has no effect on its returned value (the `out` channel): the goal of "`gen()`" is to "generate" that `out` channel.

`main` can use `out` (as the returned value of `gen()`) long after `gen()` terminates.

The literal `go func` within `gen()` still runs, even if `gen()` is terminated.

---

As noted by [vagabond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557145/vagabond) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602308/returning-channels-golang/28602514#comment122311427_28602514):

> When `gen()` returns, there is still a reference to the `out` channel, which makes it not garbage collected.
> It doesn't matter if the `gen()` has a go routine closure is using the channel.
>
> When a channel is not used, the sender can close the channel explicitly.
> And then the select for the channel will make the go routine to exit.
> At last, everything will be cleared.

Comment: ,Thanks for quick reply.I got your point,But out channel is passed to main function through  return value of gen() function.So when gen() is terminated How it is possible ?

Comment: gen may be terminated, but its internal literal go func remains, as an independent goroutine.

Comment: variable 'c' in main is return of gen() function.So what you are saying is ,It will be populated with values even after gen() terminated due to  live go routine inside gen() ...

Comment: @faisalkk yes, since the go func is a goroutine which will run asynchronously, even if gen() terminates. I have edited the answer.

Comment: when gen() returns, there is still a reference to the out channel, which makes it not garbage collected.  it doesn't matter if the gen() has a go routine closure is using the channel.

Comment: @vagabond I agree. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @VonC, normally you don't need to care about garbage collection, because go will automatically do it. when a channel is not used, the sender can close the channel explicitly.  and then the select for the channel will make the go routine to exit. at last everything will be cleared.

Comment: @vagabond Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

Because `gen()` fires off the channel population function as a goroutine;

```
go func() {
    for _, n := range nums {
        out <- n
    }
    close(out)
}()
```

and it blocks when the first value is sent on the `out` channel, because nothing is receiving yet (unbuffered channels block on sending until something receives on them), that goroutine *doesn't end when the `gen()` function returns*.

The receives from `c` in `main()`

```
fmt.Println(<-c)
...
```

then cause the goroutine started in `gen()` to keep populating the channel as the results are read out, and then finally `main()` returns when the goroutine returns, because there is nothing left to send on `out`, and nothing left to receive on `c`.

Also, the `c := make(<-chan int)` in `main()` is unnecessary as `gen()` creates a channel and returns it.

See [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3khu51rNvf)

Comment: @Internet I'm clear on your point :" goroutine doesn't end when the gen() function returns." But main function getting out channel as return from gen() function .How it is possible to get it after gen() is terminated?That is my doubt...sorry if I;m asking stupid questions,I'm new to this...

Comment: @faisalkk the `gen()` function returns the channel, then ends. The channel isn't "owned" by that function, it's just created and returned (For illustration, the goroutine can be seen as a separate "background" function, that is "disowned" by the use of the `go` keyword.). At that point the `gen()` function is free to end, and the channel can be used by other functions.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you want: https://play.golang.org/p/WSBUPPyQiY6

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func read() (elemChan chan int) {
    elemChan = make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for k := 0; k < 1000; k++ {
            elemChan <- k
        }
        close(elemChan)
    }()
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    elemChan := read()
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for k := 0; k < 2; k++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(k int) {
            for {
                e, more := <-elemChan
                if !more {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
                fmt.Printf("goroutine #%d: %d\n", k, e)
                time.Sleep(1000 * time.Nanosecond)
            }
        }(k)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Actually that was a doubt about how parallel/concurrent flow of execution happen and it was answered well. Please add enough comments or explanation instead of pasting code snippets here.

Comment: I believe a code example showing how to return an open channel for other consumers to use can be helpful for the community. Other users in this thread have thoroughly commented and answered the questions, and I think the only thing that was still missing was a working example.