# Why does this code stall?

Tags: go, concurrency

The main go routine places a ball on a channel.  The player goroutine gets the ball, manipulates it, then places the ball back on the channel and loops.  At this point it stalls.

Why does the player goroutine stall?  Shouldn't it be able to pick up the "ball" from itself?  Sorry if this is staring me right in the face, but my understanding of golang concurrency leads me to believe the player go routine should be able to play ping pong all by itself.

```
type Ball struct{ hits int }


func main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("pong", table)

    table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    <-table // game over; grab the ball
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball) {
    for {

        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the comments on the accepted answer to get a better understanding of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not stall.
It just exits.

That is because the player, when sending back the Ball, will have to wait for the `main` routine to pick it up.
And once the main routine has received the ball... it exits.
That interrupts all current goroutine, meaning the loop done by player is stopped.

The [actual example](http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/#ping-pong) is here... and it has *two* players.

Just add:

```
go player("ping", table)
```

And you [will see (playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/8SzhHzERUmS):

```
ping 1
pong 2
ping 3
pong 4
ping 5
pong 6
ping 7
pong 8
ping 9
pong 10
ping 11
pong 12
```

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204416/user3204416) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941261/why-does-this-code-stall/48941874#comment84924909_48941874):

> I meant, why doesn't it loop more than once in `player`?
>   If you increase the sleep time to 10 it becomes more evident

Here is a [playground example with `main` waiting 10 seconds](https://play.golang.org/p/45xwnhK_KTY).

`player` won't loop because `table` is an **unbuffered channel**: once player send the Ball back, player **blocks** until anyone removes that Ball from table.
And there is nobody to remove said `Ball`: `main` is sleeping 10 seconds, then removes it and *exits* immediately, preventing player to loop some more (because the *all* program has stopped)

See "[do Golang channels maintain order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25795236/6309)", in order to see an illustration of unbuffered vs. buffered channels.

With table sleeping 10 seconds, *but* with a *buffered* channel (of capacity 1), [here is what you would see (playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/LANYNLz7wN1) (the player sleeps 1 second):

```
pong 1
pong 2
pong 3
pong 4
pong 5
pong 6
pong 7
pong 8
pong 9
pong 10
pong 11
time's up
```

That is: the `player 1` pick itself the `Ball` from the `table`, and send it back to the table. It does not block because the buffered channel is not over-capacity.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't specific enough in my question. I meant, why doesn't it loop more than once in player. If you increase the sleep time to 10 it becomes more evident

Comment: @user3204416 I have edited the answer accordingly, and provide other playground examples to illustrate that behavior.

Comment: awesome thanks.  I did not know channels held on send and receive.

Comment: @user3204416 in your case, an *unbuffered* channel will held on send and receive. As I illustrated, an *buffered* one would not (at least if you don't put/receive more than one Ball at a time).